# While stacking filters, can polarizing filter be placed behind ND filters?

Tags: filters, polarizer, filter-stacking, nd-filter

I have a ND filter (10-stop, 100mmX100mm square size) with a filter holder. The filter holder  (similar to LEE or Formatt-Hitech holders) connects to the camera with a screw-in adapter (77mm and 82mm). This particular adapter has a rotating element which I guess is for circular polzrizers. With this design, I have to stack the ND filter on top of CPL.

My question is, is it good to have such a set up (CPL before ND filter)? Or, it should be other way?

Comment: I do this without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can do that. The Lee systems(and the associated competitors) are built this way as it causes no issue. In a related question and answer I displayed how I achieve this same thing: [How to mount a circular ND filter in front of the ND graduated filter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45210/4892)

Here is an image from that answer:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Due to the *small* chance of birefringence in the ND filter (likely only if the glass is stressed or if made of plastic), the ND should be closer to the camera. This is most likely just a theoretical issue with good quality filters, though you can see color fringing when photographing though plastic windows; see http://www.me.umn.edu/courses/old_me_course_pages/me5247/Photoelasticity/BasicConcepts/basicconcepts.html.